# PyLint failing for a number of Django imports

Tags: django, pylint

I am using [PyLint](https://www.pylint.org/),

```
pylint -e app/views.py
```

Gives me errors like

```
E:  3: No name 'shortcuts' in module 'django'
E:  7: No name 'db' in module 'django'
```

But passes for other django imports. Since it passes for other Django import Django is on my pythonpath.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, ID:E0611 No name 'db' in module 'django' - it's very baffling because as you say, it passes for other django imports just fine (such as django.http or django.template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out -- if you jump into a python session and actually try to import anything from django.db

```
from django.db import *
```

you'll get an error about `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` not being set. Setting the environment variable and pointing it to your `settings.py` like  `app.settings` should fix the error for you.

When I tried this in an Eclipse/PyDev config I had to disable pylint, build, then re-enable pylint to finally clear out those errors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [djangolint](http://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/django-lint/), which is a wrapper around Pylint with Django-specific settings?